# TypeError: value #0 - unsupported type: datetime.timedelta

Tags: arcpy, error, python-2.7, datetime

The following code runs fine minus receiving the error below, which doesn't make any sense (to me) as I have other `UpdateCursors` and perform `UpdateRow(row)` with other date values. As can be seen below, there are other instances in which I update a row using a "DATE" value, but for some reason this one is throwing an error.

Error:

> ...line 79, in  cursor.updateRow(row) TypeError: value #0 -
>   unsupported type: datetime.timedelta

Code that receives error:

```
# UpdateCursor that will write the time difference calculation to the new Total_Time field
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(queryLayer, "Total_Time")
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = timeDiff
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Entire code:

```
# import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Ask user to select the Geodatabase workspace to use for data output
userWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Set workspace environment based upon user's choice
arcpy.env.workspace = userWorkspace

# Ask user to select an Oracle dB Connection
oracleDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Ask user to name the Query Layer
queryLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Ask user for an SQL Query Expression to be run against the selected Oracle dB
sqlQuery = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

# Create spatial reference variable to assign to queryLayer
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference("W:\Coordinate Systems\WGS 1984.prj")

# Process: 'Make Query Layer' - Creates a Query Layer using the user's Oracle dB and SQL query expression
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(oracleDB, "Temp_Layer", sqlQuery, "UNIQUE_ID", "POLYLINE", "1050010", spatialRef)

# Process: 'Copy Features' - Copies the temporary Query Layer and stores it as a permanent feature class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Temp_Layer", queryLayer)

# Process: 'Define Projection' - Defines the projection of queryLayer feature class output
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(queryLayer, spatialRef)

# Process: 'Add Field' - Adds new column fields to queryLayer
arcpy.AddField_management(queryLayer, "First_Time", "DATE") # The first LOGDT ping
arcpy.AddField_management(queryLayer, "Last_Time", "DATE") # The last LOGDT ping
arcpy.AddField_management(queryLayer, "Total_Time", "DATE") # Summation of the first to last ping in time
arcpy.AddField_management(queryLayer, "Total_Pings", "INTEGER") # Total number of pings (rows)
arcpy.AddField_management(queryLayer, "Perfect_Pings", "INTEGER") # Total number of pings possible in given timeframe
arcpy.AddField_management(queryLayer, "Time_to_Process", "DATE") # How long it took for each ping to process

# Calculates the total number of rows for newly added column Total_Pings
numRows = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(queryLayer).getOutput(0))

# UpdateCursor that will write the value of numRows to the Total_Pings column
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(queryLayer, "Total_Pings")
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = numRows
    cursor.updateRow(row)

# SearchCursor that will read the values of LOGDT and return the first value (earliest time)
firstLogdt = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(queryLayer, "LOGDT")][0]

# UpdateCursor that will write the first (earliest time) LOGDT value to the field First_Time
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(queryLayer, "First_Time")
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = firstLogdt
    cursor.updateRow(row)

# SearchCursor that will read the values of LOGDT and return the last value (latest time)
lastLogdt = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(queryLayer, "LOGDT")][-1]

# UpdateCursor that will write the last (latest time) LOGDT value to the field Last_Time
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(queryLayer, "Last_Time")
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = lastLogdt
    cursor.updateRow(row)

# Calculates the difference between firstLogdt and lastLogdt
timeDiff = lastLogdt - firstLogdt

# UpdateCursor that will write the time difference calculation to the new Total_Time field
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(queryLayer, "Total_Time")
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = timeDiff
    cursor.updateRow(row)

# Calculates the total number of pings that would occur if no pings were dropped
perfectPings = timeDiff.total_seconds() / 5 # 1 ping every 5 seconds (with good reception)

# UpdateCursor that will write the total number of pings possible to the new Perfect_Pings field
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(queryLayer, "Perfect_Pings")
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = perfectPings
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

EDIT: As suggested, trying to cast the variable timeDiff as a string does not work and returns this:
`RuntimeError: The value type is incompatible with the field type. [Total_Time]`

Comment: @BenSNadler - I thought the same thing, but that wouldn't make any sense as I have other instances of this that run just fine. I did try it anyhow and received this new error: `RuntimeError: The value type is incompatible with the field type. [Total_Time]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line here creates a timedelta object:

```
# Calculates the difference between firstLogdt and lastLogdt
timeDiff = lastLogdt - firstLogdt
```

A datetime object is different type than a timedelta. The timedelta object doesn't fit with a date field (hence the TypeError).

You could instead create a **double** field instead of a date field, and store the difference in seconds (or do a little extra math if you wanted minutes, hours, etc.)

```
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = timeDiff.total_seconds()
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: +1 @JumpInTheFire is trying to update a field that is expecting `<type 'datetime.datetime'>` object with a `<type 'datetime.timedelta'>` object.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I was previously unaware of the two distinct differences (datetime and timedelta). Now I'm curious as to why a datetime value with some sort of arithmetic involved cannot output another datetime value?

Comment: @JumpInTheFire. Check out PyMOTW, which as always gives a good walkthrough: http://pymotw.com/2/datetime/